Shelve visible on Windows client but not on Unix client
I have a shelved changelist which I created from my Windows client, the same is visible here but when I open it from some Unix client I don't see any changes, also unshelving tells me that the file was changed but does not really unshelves the file.
himanshuman:a/b/c/d/rules> p4 describe -s 923457
Change 923457 by himanshuman@himanshu_base on 2024/05/09 01:14:59 *pending*

    Updating xml for the payload

Affected files ...

When I run the same command on windows cmd
I see files under "Affected files". Why is this happening?

Are you using the same user in both cases?  Do both users/IPs have permission to view the file(s)?  Are you sure you shelved the right version of the file?

same user and yes right version shelved

Might need to contact support, or update the question to provide an MRE.

to list the shelved files in the change use the -S flag:  p4 describe -sS 923457
